# Increasing values in a c# Database

Tags: c#

I am trying to increase the value from a database after each row is added to a label, I get it to increase until the 3rd Invoice. Here is my code:

```
 public void loadInv()
    {

>declare variables

        int i;
        int y;
        y = 0;
        i = 1;

>declare data source

        string datasource = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-VVM3FB0\WARRENDB;Initial Catalog=mAdjustments; User ID=WarrenDB; password=//purposely taken out; ";

>declare selectquery variable

        string selectQuery;

>create sql connection

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(datasource);

>open sql connection

        con.Open();

>initialize the select query with sql query

        selectQuery = @"SELECT MAX(InvoiceNum) FROM Invoices";

>initialize command with parameter of select query with connection

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, con);

> declare data reader and execute the command

        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

>conditional statement while reader is reading from database

        while (dr.Read())
        {

>if database has no row

            if (dr.IsDBNull(y))
            {
                lblInvNum.Text = 1.ToString();
            }

>if database has row

            else if (dr.HasRows)
            {

>>count the amount on the field and add 1

                i = dr.FieldCount + 1;
                i =  i + 1;

>>assign to label

                lblInvNum.Text = i.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Hi Warren, a few tips on how to improve your question: (1) pick a shorter title that describes the essence of your problem. Move the actual question (as it stands in the title right now) to the start of your content. (2) use normal C# comments in between your code lines, not markdown quotes. It really stretches your code and makes it harder to read. (3) describe a bit more of your problem. You talk about changing your values (increase), but your code only contains a select SQL statement

Answer (score -1):

It seems u are looking for last inserted row so you can use output parameter in sql query and scope_variable to return last inserted row ID to your out parameter